# Homebrew: SHA1 Mismatch Even After Update

Tags: homebrew

- Mac OS X 10.7.4 (Lion)
- Homebrew 0.9.2

Fresh install of Homebrew. No program will install on its own—the expected hash signature never matches the actual one, for whatever reason.

The only answer I have found online is to do `brew update` beforehand. I did this, and deleted the previously-downloaded package, but it doesn’t seem to have any effect:

```
 $ brew update
 Already up-to-date.
 $ brew install sshfs
 ==> Installing sshfs dependency: autoconf
 ==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
 ######################################################################## 100.0%
 Error: SHA1 mismatch
 Expected: 562471cbcb0dd0fa42a76665acf0dbb68479b78a
 Actual: 304f244353d8b7694914ff42fa87f31608728aed
 Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
 (To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.)
```

What’s going on?

**Edit**: If I download a package manually, and put it into `/Library/Caches/Homebrew/` with the same filename that Homebrew expects, and then try to install, it works fine. But if I let Homebrew try to fetch the file itself, the download ends prematurely after only a few kilobytes which corrupts the file and causes the hashes not to match.

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36862/install-homebrew-package-and-ignore-md5-hash

Comment: My downloads are corrupting so ignoring the hashes would be asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so it turns out the problem was not with Homebrew, but with cURL, which was only downloading 2 KB of whatever file I threw at it and then failing. I was able to fix this by installing the latest version of cURL.

Steps taken to resolve:

1. Opened http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.27.0.tar.gz in a web browser, saved to `/Library/Caches/Homebrew/`.
2. Ran `brew install curl`.
3. Any time I got a hash mismatch when downloading a dependency, I did steps 1 and 2 again, replacing the cURL package location with the one listed in the console output for the respective dependency.
4. By default, OS X uses `/usr/bin/curl`, whereas the Homebrew version apparently lived in `/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.27.0/bin/curl`. Which actually should have been symlinked as `/usr/local/bin/curl`, but wasn’t for some reason—`brew link curl` fixed that though (may have had to repeat for dependencies).
5. However, Homebrew apparently has the philosophy that it’s desirable to always use Apple’s system-default binaries if they’re available. Wasn’t in my case, so I followed [this advice](https://superuser.com/a/324617/56559) and added `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to my bash profile, to do the reverse, and always use Homebrew binaries first, despite whatever bleeding edge repercussions that may have.
6. `brew update`.
7. `brew install sshfs`—success!

Many thanks to Ian C. for taking the time to chat with me and point me in the right direction.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear you got it working!

Answer (score 5):

If you're certain the downloaded tarball for `sshfs` is good can try to force Homebrew to install it with:

```
brew install -f sshfs
```

More than likely though, if it still complains, is you've got a corrupt tarball download. You can remove `/usr/local/Cellar/sshfs/2.4.0/sshfs_2_4_0`, which is the cached tarball that Homebrew downloaded, and have Homebrew try downloading the package anew.

If it still complains about the hash value mismatch, you can edit the recipe and update the MD5 checksum for the file in the recipe and then install. The file to edit is `/usr/local/Library/Formula/sshfs.rb`. Looking at:

```
/Users/ian/code/tmp/brew [ian@Ian-Chesals-MacBook-Pro] [13:13]
> cat /usr/local/Library/Formula/sshfs.rb
require 'formula'

class Sshfs < Formula
  homepage 'http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html'
  url 'https://github.com/fuse4x/sshfs/tarball/sshfs_2_4_0'
  md5 'c9ea547b9684ec4d85437393a2731322'
  version '2.4.0'

  depends_on :automake
  depends_on :libtool

  depends_on 'pkg-config' => :build
  depends_on 'fuse4x'
  depends_on 'glib'

  def install
    system "autoreconf", "--force", "--install"
    system "./configure", "--disable-debug", "--disable-dependency-tracking",
                          "--prefix=#{prefix}"
    system "make install"
  end

  def caveats; <<-EOS.undent
    Make sure to follow the directions given by `brew info fuse4x-kext`
    before trying to use a FUSE-based filesystem.
    EOS
  end
end
```

You can see that you need to download https://github.com/fuse4x/sshfs/tarball/sshfs_2_4_0 and recalculate the MD5 checksum for the file and then update the recipe. So:

```
/Users/ian/code/tmp/brew [ian@Ian-Cs-MacBook-Pro] [13:13]
> wget https://github.com/fuse4x/sshfs/tarball/sshfs_2_4_0
--2012-07-23 13:13:53--  https://github.com/fuse4x/sshfs/tarball/sshfs_2_4_0
Resolving github.com... 207.97.227.239
Connecting to github.com|207.97.227.239|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://nodeload.github.com/fuse4x/sshfs/tarball/sshfs_2_4_0 [following]
--2012-07-23 13:13:53--  https://nodeload.github.com/fuse4x/sshfs/tarball/sshfs_2_4_0
Resolving nodeload.github.com... 207.97.227.252
Connecting to nodeload.github.com|207.97.227.252|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 52812 (52K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `sshfs_2_4_0'

100%[===========================================================================================>] 52,812       288K/s   in 0.2s    

2012-07-23 13:13:54 (288 KB/s) - `sshfs_2_4_0' saved [52812/52812]


/Users/ian/code/tmp/brew [ian@Ian-Cs-MacBook-Pro] [13:13]
> md5 sshfs_2_4_0 
MD5 (sshfs_2_4_0) = c9ea547b9684ec4d85437393a2731322
```

In my case the computed value for the download matches the value in the recipe. If it's different for your case it's likely your download is corrupt. You can go ahead and update the recipe if you think your download is not corrupt.

Note: I did a `brew update` before running the above so I can attest to the fact that I do have the latest recipe for `sshfs` and that the MD5 checksum for the tarball in the recipe is correct and matches what gets downloaded from github.

*Caveat Utilitor* if you do this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions, but unfortunately this doesn’t help. The mismatch happens for every single program I try to download—it seems they are all corrupted on arrival.

Comment: That's likely a bigger issue then. Are you behind a corporate firewall that might be zeroing out files that end in specific extensions?

Comment: Nope, I’m not. As I say in the edited OP, I can download tarballs outside of Homebrew, and they won’t corrupt.

Comment: How are you downloading the file? IIRC homebrew uses curl. If you curl the file, does it download okay? Try setting HOMEBREW_DEBUG=1 and HOMEBREW_CURL_VERBOSE=1 in your environment before calling homebrew to install something and see if says more about what it's doing.

Comment: Curl doesn’t seem to be downloading the full files. Wget does, however. I set the environment vars but oddly didn’t see any actual difference in output when attempting to install again.

Comment: So it's a curl issue on your machine. Not sure how to help you with that, sorry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4429/discussion-between-ian-c-and-hugh-guiney)

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem when trying to install sdl_image (brew install sdl_image)

```
brew install sdl_image
==> Downloading http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL_image-1.2.1
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 5e3e393d4e366638048bbb10d6a269ea3f4e4cf2
Actual: 96553a2470b51f5cca98d9c390c56bacd12f8ed4
```

However, got it working after realizing I was behind a server that zeros/breaks files if they exceed a certain size hence being corrupted. Solved it by moving to another network and trying to reinstall. Though I got the same error I knew the file was complete because the expected sha given the previous errors was now given in the actual sha.

Then to successfully complete as I came across trying to solve the problem was to `brew edit sdl_image` and copy the actual sha to the sha in the file.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with zlib-1.2.8.  The root cause though was that I had a `.curlrc` file that specified `--compressed`, and that option causes curl to decompress the file before writing it out.

Removing the option fixed the problem for me, but I don't know if there's a better fix available.